# AWS Elastic beanstalk cname with and without www

Tags: amazon-web-services, cname-record, amazon-route53

So, I've got a website running in Elastic beanstalk on AWS and I have a custom domain name which points to it, which is managed in Route 53.  When I set up the custom domain initially, I just looked up the IP of the default domain name (xxxx.eu-north-1.elasticbeanstalk.com) and then just created a couple of A records (with and without www) which pointed to that IP address and all was well

Then I discovered that the public IP address of the elastic beanstalk envrionment does not seem to be static.  It changes every few months, which means that I had to periodically go and change the A records so they would point to the updated IP.  Then I discovered that I could create a CNAME record instead which basically points directly to xxxx.eu-north-1.elasticbeanstalk.com, instead of the IP address .  So I created a CNAME record which has www prepended and that works great, even if the IP address changes.  However, I cannot seem to be able to create another CNAME record without the www, so that had to remain as an A record which points to an IP address which I still have to update everytime the IP address changes.

Is it not possible to have two CNAME records in the same zone?  Both pointing to xxxx.eu-north-1.elasticbeanstalk.com ?  How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've figured out how to do this ... I changed the existing A record to an Alias which points to my elastic beanstalk environment.  Let's wait and see if works.